# Reset all vim shortcuts and redefine just some of them

Tags: vim

I want to learn to use vim. The thing is simple : **I don't know any of its shortcuts**. So I don't want to bother learning them, I want to define my own, for every command !

1. Is there a way to disable all the commands, and only enable those I've set ?
2. How to redefine the most basic commands ? like insert, move up, move left, exit insert mode... ? I've found a lot of tutorials about specific commands, but none about the most basic ones.

Thanks

**Edit** : Please... Can I get a real answer, instead of "are you sure ?"

***Edit 2** : The main reason for this is that I'm on a **dvorak keyboard**, so it's not like the shortkeys are mapped to the letters I see... This makes it difficult :p. And second, I want to be **super efficient**... Like mapping the up, down, left and right key to "j, k, l, ;", it will enable me to edit a file without moving my hands around. Finally, **I HATE when I type a wrong key**, and I don't know what vim (or any other tool) did because it was a shortcut/command but I don't know what it did because I don't know it yet. And why learn shortcuts when you can make your own, that you can remember better... I'm french so some letters are not mapped in my mind like it would be for english speakers.*

Comment: well, excuse my bluntness, but I must confide that I think you are stacking up anawful lot of handicaps there (blind keyboard, nonstandard layout, personal aversion of typos, and... well French is ok but also... nonstandard for Vi :)). On the plus side, I **can attest** that if you care for the best approach, you _should_ pick that up from the get-go or you'll always be betwixt and between. Hat's off and cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to purge only that shortcuts that were defined using `*map`, built-in commands are overridable, but not purgable. If you need to disable particular command you will have to do `noremap <Key> <Nop>`, the following code should disable them all (but note that it is overriding, not removing anything):

```
function s:hsescape(str)
    return substitute(substitute(substitute(substitute(a:str,
                \      ' ', '<Space>',         'g'),
                \      '|', '<Bar>',           'g'),
                \     "\n", '<CR>',            'g'),
                \'\c^<\%(buffer\|silent\|expr\|special\)\@=', '<LT>', '')
endfunction
for s:mode in ['n', 'x', 'o']
    for s:char in map(range(0, 0x7F), 'nr2char(v:val)')
        execute s:mode.'noremap '.s:hsescape(s:char).' <Nop>'
    endfor
endfor
for s:mode in ['s', 'i', 'c']
    for s:char in map(range(0, 0x3F), 'nr2char(v:val)')
        execute s:mode.'noremap '.s:hsescape(s:char).' <Nop>'
    endfor
endfor
```

Note that this should be immediately followed by code that defines some mappings (or removes some of `<Nop>` ones) or you will render your vim useless.

Comment: Thank you !! This is exactly what I needed, now if I want to redefine all the commands, do you have a list that I can use to know all the commands available, and all the keys available ? (I am new to this, so I don't know what to write when I mean "Escape" for example :p)

Comment: @Matthieu There is an index of all commands in a vim help: `:h index` (to use this you will have to unmap `:` or map something to `:` in normal mode and same for `<CR>` in command mode).

Comment: Hope you figured this all out. It's probably much easier to read vim's help pages without disabling all the shortcuts like above.

Answer (score 4):

There's an entry on the vim wiki on wikia for [Using Vim with the Dvorak keyboard layout](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Vim_with_the_Dvorak_keyboard_layout) and there's a thread on SuperUser that [discusses whether or not it's worth trying to use Dvorak with vim](https://superuser.com/questions/81984/dvorak-hotkey-remapping-in-vim-worth-it)

The sentiment in both (the comments on the wiki entry and the comments/answers on the SU conversation) seem to indicate that Dvorak and vim don't really go together very well, and I'm inclined to agree.

Other than hjkl, however, most commands should still make sense from a mnemonic standpoint, shouldn't they?  And since the only real reason to use Dvorak is to increase your speed, why would you be phyiscally looking at the keys to determine what to hit?

Comment: Your links were interesting. Though I am using a french dvorak named "bépo", so this has nothing to do with standard dvorak. I will meet the same problem though I understand. Still, I wonder if it is possible to personnalize EVERY command and shortcut in Vim ? If yes, then I'll learn my own Vim, and won't be able to use it anywhere else, but i don't care.

Comment: Yes, you can personalize everything! Great, isn't it! I'm guessing you're already good with a qwerty keyboard so... maybe if you map everything so it's in the same location most of the time, then it'd work. On the other hand, if you don't map anything, then you can remember the symbols better, and just learn vim for two layouts.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest not trying to redefine the commands.  You'll be much better off learning the commands that are provided, and adding custom commands if you find something you want to do that does not exist.

If you don't like the commands, why not try a different editor?

Comment: Well the main reason is that I'm on a dvorak keyboard, so it's not like the shortkeys are mapped to the letters I see... This makes it difficult :p. And second, I want to be super efficient... Like mapping the up, down, left and right key to "j, k, l, ;", it will enable me to edit a file without moving my hands around.

Comment: It should already be mapped to hjkl... But I changed mine to uhjk so it's like arrow keys, and undo is l. :D

Comment: Wow, nevermind, I never knew about the Dvorak keyboard layout! You definitely might need to remap some stuff if you want it to be located in the same or similar place, but you might not remember the pneumonics (e.g. dw 'd'eletes a 'w'ord, y for 'y'ank, cw for 'c'hange 'w'ord, etc.).

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this, but I strongly disagree with this answer.  There are many reasons that a person would want to define their own mappings.  Vim takes the idea of predefining keymappings for everything to an absurd length.  There is no one who can, or should remember them all.  An alternative is to define functions for less common operations and let users choose their own mappings.

Answer (score 0):

I took references from the answer by ZyX and created a vimrc setup for overriding - and have tried to document the process and the functions. Hope it is helpful to someone else:

https://github.com/hiway/po